# Cancelling git push and ignore additional folder

Tags: git, gitignore, git-commit

I want to cancel the git push.
I've done it with `cntrl + C`   command.  I reset --mixed to my old status.
Add the forgetten directory to my gitignore file,
But when I do the `git push` again , it still tries to send the ignored folder.
Any ideas?

Comment: `push` doesn't send folders, it sends commits.

Comment: I mean commited folder. push -f didn't worked for me

Comment: It send the committed folder because the folder is committed. What is your question?

Comment: i get back the commit with reset. add the folder to gitignore and,
folder is not in the git status anymore, but when i commit and push again, it still tries to continue where its left from previous cancelled push

Comment: `git reset --mixed` doesn't reset commits. `--mixed` is the default, by the way. And why are you looking at status? `push` doesn't care about status, only about commits, as I already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the method actually...

git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch  ' --prune-empty -- --all

Comment: Interesting, more complete than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

If, in the old status (after the `git reset`), the folder (and its content) are still part of the index (are still listed by the git status as being "added", ready to be committed), then you need to remove them from the index.

```
git rm --cached -r /patH/to/folder
```

If you don't, the directive in the `.gitignore` file will be ignored, and the next commit would include, again, that folder.